# Opening multiple tabs in gnome-terminal, having them automatically password-lessly ssh to servers and do so using alias from my bashrc file

Tags: bash, ssh, gnome-terminal, bashrc

I regularly have to `ssh` into four or so servers we run, at the same time. I have aliased these like.

```
SERVER1=root@server1
alias sshserver1='ssh -t ${SERVER1} "bash -rcfile .my_bashrc"'
# Above line runs my specific bashrc called my_bashrc 
# (this is because many users log in as root, and we 
# have separate bashrcs for each of us. Yes, we should
# have different user accounts etc, but it is what it is).
```

My `ssh` is passwordless to these servers.

Currently I do open an instance of gnome-terminal, then tun <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> four times to open four tabs. Then cycle through them typing sshserver1 in the first, sshserver2 in the second etc. This is annoying.

What I want is to be able to create a function like

```
function sshallservers()
{
     #Function to open tabs and ssh into four servers
     1.) Open first tab, which must source specific .my_bashrc 
     to pick up the aliases, run alias sshserver1, thereby 
     ssh-ing to the relevant server.
     2.) Repeat for N servers
}
```

So I have tried with

```
gnome-terminal --tab --command "bash -c 'ssh root@server1'" 
               --tab --command "bash -c 'ssh root@server2'"
```

And this works as far as opening the tabs and `ssh`ing, however it has several problems ...

1. I do not want to do root@server1, I want to do sshserver1 (defined as an alias in my local `.my_bashrc` file. So I want somehow this to be sourced and available such that I can use this alias.
2. When the ssh command has been run, I want it to source the remote `.my_bashrc` file, this may be achieved just by being able to use the alias as my alias is defined to source this with the -rcfile flag

I cannot  find a way to make the new tab source a local `bashrc` file, and so cannot get my alias working. Since I don't have my alias working, I cannot tell ssh to run the `bash -rcfile .my_bashrc` command, so the remote `bashrc` file isn't automatically sourced either.

Comment: As I remember `alias` can't use variables inside of it - so use `function` instead. `function sshserv(){gnome-terminal --tab --command "bash -c 'ssh root@$1 "bash -rcfile .my_bashrc"'"}` and use as `sshserv server1`

Comment: With the multiple use of double quotes I get "Argument to "--command/-e" is not a valid command: Text ended before matching quote was found for '." (The text was 'bash -c 'ssh root@server1 bash')

Comment: Try this `--command="bash -c 'ssh root@$1 \"bash -rcfile .my_bashrc\"'"`

Comment: Have you considered `tmux`? it is a great tool for text-only workers. A bit of a learning curve but it pays off.

Comment: @costas, please move your answer to the answers section so that it can be marked as correct, and noticed by others arriving at this post.

Answer (score 2):

As I remember `alias` can't use variables inside of it - so use `function` instead.

```
function sshserv {
    gnome-terminal --tab --command "
        bash -c 'ssh root@$1 \"bash -rcfile .my_bashrc\"'"
}
```

and use as

```
sshserv server1
```